# Egg Hatching Sound.

Tags: sound-effects

hey. i was looking out for some egg hatching sound effects but the ones i found were of low quality with a lot of ambient noise in them. Can anyone give me suggestions as to how i can create the egg hatching sound effect using things of daily use??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about some eggs from the grocery store?

Or watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dp7aJ6zoLXY):

[youtube]Dp7aJ6zoLXY[/youtube]

Answer (score 2):

Snap/crush some crackers or chips.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking, what about try recording the sound of the cracking of a dry piece of a Baguette? As one of your layers...

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to have a separate cracking sound without the wet sound of an egg from the grocery store, you could try blowing the egg dry.  That is where you take a pin and make two small holes on an egg on at the top and one on the bottom and then you shake the egg really hard to crack the yolk inside.  Then you put your mouth over one hole and blow out the egg guts out the other hole.  Let it dry overnight and you have an empty egg shell.....then again its rather laborious.. You could just crack an egg in half and let the halves dry for the same effect.  Maybe you want something sticky for the fluids? Try honey or sticky rice for some texture.

Answer (score 0):

What is in the egg?  What is the context?  You could use some crystilline form combined with organic animal sound